# Value of $t$ for a point on the hyperbola with given parametric equation $P(t)$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions

The parametric equation of a hyperbola $\mathcal{H}$ is
$$
P(t) = O \pm \cosh(t)\vec{u} + \sinh(t)\vec{v}.
$$
Knowing the coordinates of $P(t)$, how to find $t$?

To solve a trigonometric equation $a \cos x + b \sin  x = d$, there's a [helpful formula](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-linear-combinations-to-solve-trigonometric-equations):
$$
a \cos x + b \sin  x  = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \cos\bigl(x - \textrm{arctan2}(b, a)\bigr).
$$
Is there a similar formula in hyperbolic trigonometry?

Comment: Hmm.. I think I was in a wrong way: that's easier than $a \cosh x + b \sinh  x = d$ since there are two equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the known point and the expression for the hyperbola, you will get

$ \cosh(t) = a $

$ \sinh(t) = b $

for some numbers $a$ and $b$.

but $\cosh(t) = \frac{1}{2} ( e^{t}+ e^{-t} ) $ and $\sinh(t) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{t} - e^{-t} ) $

Thus

$ a + b = e^{t} $

from which $ t = \ln(a + b) $